# How to disable hot corner in CentOS in command prompt

Tags: command-line

I downloaded gnome-tweaks and was able to do it through their GUI. I was wonder if there a way to do this on command prompt ? thank you.

Comment: This is Ubuntu forum. Not CentOS. Anyway, I think you can use the `gsettings` tool.

Comment: https://www.centos.org/forums/ is the CentOS forum, and http://unix.stackexchange.com is the universal Linux Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 1):

In most gnome implementations you can type:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell enable-hot-corners false
```

Comment: enable-hot-corners is not an option. these are my options after typing gsettings set org.gnome.shell 
always-show-log-out                    enabled-extensions 
app-picker-view                        favorite-apps 
command-history                        had-bluetooth-devices-setup 
development-tools                      looking-glass-history 
disable-extension-version-validation   remember-mount-password 
disable-user-extensions  please help